# mysql SUM(value) where SUM(value) > 2500

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a transactions table (simplified for needed columns):

```
id    client_id    value
1     1            200
2     2            150
3     1            350
4     2            100
```

I want to return client_id where sum(value) >= 500.

I tried:
`SELECT client_id, sum(value) as total FROM transactions WHERE total >= 500;`
That query returns "#1054 - Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'"

I've also tried:
`SELECT client_id, sum(value) FROM transactions WHERE sum(value) >= 500;
That query returns "#1111 - Invalid use of group function"`

I've also tried:
`SELECT client_id, sum(value) FROM transactions WHERE sum(value) >= 500 GROUP BY client_id;`
That query also returns "#1111 - Invalid use of group function"

I've spent a few hours looking and haven't been able to word the correct question to find my query, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the other answers gave the exact query, so here it is:

```
SELECT client_id
FROM transactions
GROUP BY client_id
HAVING SUM(value) >= 500;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I will remember HAVING next time I need it!

Answer (score 0):

`... HAVING SUM(value) >= 500`

In SQL, `WHERE` applies to individual row values, while `HAVING` applies to aggregate values across rows.